# How to click same button in another section while scraping using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I'm scraping using selenium and I want to click 'next' button in 'Defensive' section but the code I wrote clicks 'next' on 'Summary'.

Here's the url for you to try :

https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/7361/Stages/16368/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2018-2019

So it's selecting 'Defensive' and I can see it selected in the window but the next page doesnt appear. On  clicking 'Summary' I found out next function is actually happening there.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe") 
browser.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/7361/Stages/16368/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2018-2019')


browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="stage-top-player-stats-options"]/li[2]/a""").click()

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="next"]""")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: you can use pythonautogui for clicking.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath for next button is not unique for this page. try this,

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='stage-top-player-stats-defensive']//a[@id='next']")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

or

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='stage-top-player-stats-defensive']//a[@id='next']")))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

For each tab (Summary, Defensive, ..) new next button with same `id=next` added to the DOM. 
Select Defensive and you will see there will be two next buttons with same `id=next`, select Offensive and there will be three next buttons.
With basic `id=next` selector you always click to the first next button from Summary tab. Because you're using JavaScript and nothing happen, try to click with Selenium click method and you will get an error.
To solve the problem adjust your selector to be more specific to the dom - `#statistics-paging-defensive #next`.

Also when you first time open the page there's cookies acceptance screen appears and block the page, you can use method like below to skip it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.common.exceptions as EX


def accept_cookies():
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20)\
            .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.qc-cmp-button")))\
            .click()
    except EX.NoSuchElementException or EX.TimeoutException:
        pass

#...

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe") 
browser.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/7361/Stages/16368/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2018-2019')

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
browser.get(baseUrl)

accept_cookies()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[href='#stage-top-player-stats-defensive']"))).click()
next_button = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#statistics-paging-defensive #next")))
next_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your elements locators must be unique
2. Avoid using XPath wildcards - `*` as it will cause performance degradation and prolonged elements lookup timings
3. Avoid using JavaScriptExecutor for clicking, well-behaved Selenium test must do what real user does and I doubt that real user will be opening browser console and typing something like `document.getElementById('next').click()`, he will use the mouse

Assuming all above you should come up with a selector which uniquely identifies `next` button on `Defensive` tab which would be something like:

```
//div[@id='statistics-paging-defensive']/descendant::a[@id='next']
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)